# Two variables converging almost surely

Tags: probability-theory

If $X_{n} \rightarrow X$ almost surely and $N_{n} \rightarrow \infty$ almost surely, then is it true that $X_{N_{n}} \rightarrow X$ almost surely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Simply observe that $\mathbb{P}((X_n\to X)\cap (N_n\to \infty))=1,$ since the intersection of countably many almost sure sets is again almost sure.

However, for any $\omega \in (X_n\to X)\cap (N_n\to \infty)$, let $\varepsilon>0$ be given and $K(\omega)$ such that $|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|\leq \varepsilon$ for all $n\geq K(\omega)$ and some $M(\omega)$ such that $N_n(\omega)\geq K(\omega)$ for all $n\geq M(\omega)$. Then, for all $n\geq M(\omega)$, we have
$$
|X_{N_n}(\omega)-X(\omega)|\leq \varepsilon
$$

Thus, $(X_n\to X)\cap (N_n\to \infty)\subseteq (X_{N_n}\to X)$, establishing that the latter set is almost sure as well.

Comment: Oh... $N_n$ is a variable. I'll correct the answer.

Comment: Well, before, it simply said that $X_{N_n}$ would converge whenever $X_n$ does, which isn't true.

Comment: I see, the answer has been edited. :)